# Refer to next index in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

If I had a simple pandas DataFrame like this:

```
frame = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape((3,4)), columns=list('abcd'), index=list('123'))
```

I want find the max value from each row, and use this to find the next value in the column and add this value to a new column.

So the above DataFrame looks like this (with d2 changed to 3):

```
    a    b    c    d
1    1    2    3    4
2    5    6    7    3
3    9    10    11    12
```

So, conceptually the first row should be scanned, 4 is identified as the largest number, then 3 is found as the number within the same column but in the next index. Similarly for the row 2, 7 is the largest number, and 11 is the next number in that column. So 3 and 11 should get added to a new column like this:

```
    a    b    c    d    Next
1    1    2    3    4    NaN
2    5    6    7    3    3
3    9    10    11    12  11
```

I started by making a function like this, but it only finds the max values.

```
f = lambda x: x.max()
max = frame.apply(f, axis='columns')
frame['Next'] = max
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your edit, you can use `np.argsort`:

```
i = np.arange(len(df))
j = pd.Series(np.argmax(df.values, axis=1))

df['next'] = df.shift(-1).values[i, j] 

   a   b   c   d  next
1  1   2   3   4   3.0
2  5   6   7   3  11.0
3  9  10  11  12   NaN
```

Comment: @COLDSPEED this is close, but not quite what I was looking for. This gives the max value of each row. But I want the value in the same column but next index of the max value in each row. I tried to make the example a bit more clear.